# How to filter the Kendo Grid data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo grid in my view . How can i filter my data in the grid. my grid get data from a list in my model .

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.list)
    .Name("listgrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("status");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource)
)
```

No i want to filter my grid on basis of the field Name . I tried

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{name: "sasdas"}],
    filter: {
        logic: "or",
        filters:[
            { field: "Name", operator: "eq", value: "null" },
            { field: "Name", operator: "eq", value: "" }
        ]
    }
});
```

what i am doing wrong here .

Comment: Just a typo, fix `Datasource` to `DataSource`.

Comment: that was a typo here .. it does not apply filter on it after that  ..

Comment: You're defining the datasource as `.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource)` but creating a new one with different *data*. Can't get what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `DataSource`'s `Filter` method within Razor?

Comment: Just want to send the listgrid data into the filter e.g. in data:[] .. instead of   data:[name:"sasdas"]

Comment: @CarstenFranke  how's that ?

Comment: You have created a grid with razor(lets call it *A*) and created a dataSource(*B*) in javascript. You're filtering *B*, not *A*.

Comment: yes @DontVoteMeDown  thats what i am asking . how to just send my dataSource(A) to the filter .. As i am new to Kendo .

Comment: I am still not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Where are your data coming from? Is it a controller in your ASP.NET application? If so, is it an option to return the data already filtered? Should the users be able to change the filters afterwards or is this filter final?

Comment: Adding to Carsten's comment - I would highly recommend an AJAX approach. See [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). Create a controller Read method to populate the grid with a `DataSourceRequest` to handle the paging, sorting, grouping, and column filtering. The Read method can be parameterized to deal with custom filtering.

Comment: @CarstenFranke yes i am using this in my MVC application .. i already did the filtering from the controller and its kind of messier of building different lists for filtering . But i thought if i could do it here just sending the single list from controller and do he filtering here on client side thats why .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scenario 1: If you want separate rows for filters

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.list)
        .Name("listgrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
            columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("status").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource)
    )
```

scenario 2:Filter Menu Customization :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.list)
        .Name("listgrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("status");
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
            ))
        )   
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource)
    )
```

Comment: and try to read data using read action on the DataSource like below        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Remote_Binding_Orders_Read", "Grid"))
     )

Comment: Reference:   https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/remote-data-binding